# problem with delayed loops

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm having a nightmare trying to get some quotes to loop with a delay. I have created the following code:

```
function loopquotes(){
 var items = $('.comment').size();
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*items+1);
 $(".comment:nth-child("+randomNum+")").fadeIn('slow').delay(5000);
 $(".comment:nth-child("+randomNum+")").fadeOut('medium');
}
```

This fades in and out nicely with the delay. However, the loop keeps looping without using the delay and I end up with loads of quotes on the page. Can anybody help me loop this properly so that a new quote is only loaded after the old one has faded out.

Many thanks

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the function again as a callback, like this:

```
function LoopQuotes(){
  var comments = $('.comment'),
      rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*comments.length+1);
  comments.eq(rand).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('medium', LoopQuotes);
}
```

Then just called this once on page load, e.g. with a `document.ready` call, like this:

```
$(LoopQuotes);
```

What this does is fade in a quote, delay 5000ms, fade it out, then when the [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) completes, call the function again to pick/show the next quote.

Comment: Hi Nick,Many thanks for that solution its been driving me nuts. I have posted a small fix to your solution as yours does loop correctly, but won't get another quote on the second run through. The below code seems to now work though.

Comment: function LoopQuotes(){
 var size = $('.comment').size();
 rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*size+1);
 $(".comment:nth-child("+rand+")").fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('medium', LoopQuotes);
}